# DQL association error when run query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

Im new in DQL and doctrine 2 so, please be patient.
I have this query:

`select c, m from A10\CrmBundle\Entity\Crm c inner join c.irszam m on m.irszam = c.cim1irszam where c.kod = ?1`

I get this error back:

`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 64 near 'm on m.irszam': Error: Class A10\CrmBundle\Entity\Crm has no association named irszam`

Entities:

```
  class Crm
    {
        /**
         * @Id 
         * @OneToOne(targetEntity="megye", mappedBy="kod")
         *
         */
        protected $kod;
        ...
    }

   class Megye
    {

       ...

        /**
         * @OneToOne(targetEntity="crm", inversedBy="irszam")
         * @JoinColumn(name="irszam_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         * @Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $irszam;
       ...
    }
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "on" by "with" in your query. Also, you are using [identity (@Id) through foreign entities (@OneToOne)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities), so make sure you're using Doctrine 2.1 (which is already at [Release Candidate](http://www.doctrine-project.org/downloads/DoctrineORM-2.1.0RC1-full.tar.gz) state), because that functionality is not available in 2.0.x series.

Also, I think you have an error in your association mapping. I think what you really want to do is:

```
class Crm
{
    /**
     * @Id 
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="megye", mappedBy="irszam")
     *
     */
    protected $kod;
    ...
}

class Megye
{

   ...

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="crm", inversedBy="kod")
     * @JoinColumn(name="irszam_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $irszam;
   ...
}
```

In other words, you have to switch the mappedBy and inversedBy mapping properties, as defined [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional). You probably will have to recreate the DB schema after these changes.

Comment: I use doctrine 2.1.0RC2 version. I replaced "on" with "with" but unfortunately don't solved the problem. Maybe, is it Association Mapping problem?

Comment: Hi, I think so, I updated my answer to reflect that. Nonetheless I also maintain my initial suggestion (WITH instead of ON), but let me know how it goes.

Comment: I made it as you suggested but it dosn't work. I dont really understand the association mapping. But in postgreSQL this query is running.

Comment: Beware that DQL is not like normal SQL, so you can't use one were you use the other. In DQL you think in terms of objects, not DB tables. Take a closer look at the DQL documentation: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html